# dictionary key mapping in python

Tags: python, dictionary

After parsing a .txt file of strings, I have created two dictionaries.

Dict1 is a pairing of key(string) : value(list[string]].

Dict2 is an enumeration of dict1 such that key(int) : value(string--the key from dict1)

I am trying to create a third dictionary with the values from dict1 as a vector/list in the form key(int): Value (list[int])

```
dict1 = {'Foo': ['Lorem', 'Ipsum'], 'Bar':['Dolor', 'Sit', 'Amet'], 'Baz':['Consectetur', 'Adipiscing', 'Elit', 'Sed'], 'Lorem':['Foo', 'Do']}
    
   
dict2 = {1: 'Foo', 2: 'Bar', 3: 'Baz', 4: 'Lorem', 5: 'Ipsum', 6: 'Dolor', 7: 'Sit', 8: 'Amet', 9: 'Consectetur', 10: 'Adipiscing', 11: 'Elit', 12: 'Sed', 13: 'Do'}
```

For instance, I want

```
dict3 = {1: [4, 5], 2: [6, 7, 8], 3:[9, 10, 11, 12], 4:[1, 13]... & so on}
```

What would be an efficient way to go about this?

Comment: I am thinking to parse the lines in the .txt file twice. The first would establish a mapping of names to keys in int form.
The second read would be to determine the values of the first keys (using the previous key mapping).

Comment: Good question @Peter, next time please provide working Python code that we can reproduce. For example `dict1 = {'Foo': ['Lorem', 'Ipsum'], 'Bar':['Dolor', 'Sit', 'Amet']}` instead of `dict1 = {'Foo': ['Lorem', 'Ipsum'], 'Bar':['Dolor', 'Sit', 'Amet'], 'Baz':['...']}`. This will make the life of those who reply simpler, so it's more likely that you get a reply. Much appreciated if you decide to edit your question now.

Comment: @edd313 Thank you for the suggestion. Can I improve further?

Comment: Well done, you can change `dict3` accordingly. Also, you don't need to show 'baz' and 'loren' in my opinion. You should always keep your example [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See my answer below to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instinct you have in your comment is correct, start by making a new mapping that is the reverse of dict2:

```
dict4 = {v: k for k, v in dict2.items()}
```

Then you can create dict3 with the following (admittedly complex) nesting of `dict` and `list` comprehensions:

```
dict3 = {k: [dict4[v2] for v2 in dict1[v] if v2 in dict4] for k, v in dict2.items() if v in dict1}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not going to be a particularly efficient way to approach this since this is almost by design a O(n) or O(n * m) problem. The best way is going to be to iterate through `dict1` to access each key's `int` value, and do the same for each value in the associated value list:

```py
dict3 = dict()

for key, value in dict1.items():
    key_int = dict2[key]
    value_ints = [dict2[i] for i in value]

    dict3[key_int] = value_ints
```

or as a comprehension:

```py
dict3 = { dict2[key]: [dict2[i] for i in value] for key, value in dict1.items() }
```

Make sure you are wrapping either solution in a `try` block to catch an `KeyError`s that might be raised for a value in `dict` that isn't present in `dict2`

Answer (score 1):

```py
# original dicts
dict1 = {'Foo': ['Lorem', 'Ipsum'], 'Bar':['Dolor', 'Sit', 'Amet']}
dict2 = {1: 'Foo', 2: 'Bar', 3: 'Baz', 4: 'Lorem', 5: 'Ipsum', 6: 'Dolor', 7: 'Sit', 8: 'Amet' }

# invert keys and vals from dict2
d2_index = { v: i for i, v in zip( dict2.keys(), dict2.values() ) }

# map indices to values
{
    d2_index[ k ]: [
        d2_index[ v ]
        for v in vs
    ]
    for k, vs in dict1.items()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can swap keys and values of `dict2`

```
dict1 = {'Foo': ['Lorem', 'Ipsum'], 'Bar':['Dolor', 'Sit', 'Amet']}
dict2 = {1: 'Foo', 2: 'Bar', 3: 'Lorem', 4: 'Ipsum', 5: 'Dolor', 6: 'Sit', 7: 'Amet'}

dict2_reversed = {value: key for key, value in dict2.items()}
```

Then use a dictionary comprehension to create the final dictionary. You also need a nested list comprehension for the values:

```
>>> {dict2_reversed[key]: [dict2_reversed[v] for v in value] 
     for key, value in dict1.items()}
{1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6, 7]}
```